# Trying to prove that a triangular number equation has no solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to prove -- using elementary math only -- that the following equation has no integer solutions for $t \ge 1$:

$$ 6a^2(16a^2+1) = \frac{t(t+1)}{2}. \qquad(1)$$

I know it doesn't (or at least *shouldn't*), because I derived it from a known equation with only one solution ($t=a=0$). Just to be sure, I also confirmed (using maxima) that there are no solutions with $1 \le a \le 10000$.

Any thoughts on how to continue algebraically from $(1)$ would be appreciated.

EDIT: Another equivalent reduction (if it's easier to work with) would be

$$ (6x^2+1)^2+3(2x^2)^2 = y^2. $$

[Proof: Clearly y is odd. Now reducing modulo 8, we see that x must be even. Substitute y=2t+1 and x=2a and simplify to get (1).]

Thanks!
Kieren.

Comment: real solutions?integer solutions?

Comment: Sorry… integer solutions!

Comment: To those who suggested the quadratic formula, a big thanks: that gives me enough to work with! I must admit, I feel a little silly (and humbled) not to have thought to use it myself.

Comment: But this will not help you, I think. You need something about the numbers which are representated by $x^2+3y^2$

Comment: Hmmmmm… that may well be. I'll report back after doing a little algebra.

Comment: Can you help us why the second equation, i.e., $48x^4 + 12x^2 - y^2 + 1=0$, is equivalent to $(1)$, which is $192a^4 + 12a^2 - t^2 - t=0$ ?

Comment: In
$$ 48x^4+12x^2+1=y^2,$$
clearly $y$ is odd. Now reducing modulo $8$, we see that $x$ must be even. Substitute $y=2t+1$ and $x=2a$ and simplify to get (1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: You were right, in that the quadratic formula avenue was a bit of a dead end. However, I believe I was able to prove that (1) has no positive integer solutions. I am drawing up a paper for submission to a journal — when that's either published or rejected, I'll be sure to report back.